# Gulp output on Windows CMD is unreadable

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, gulp

I have recently started using gulp with windows cmd (also tried using powershell), and the output is colored in such a way that no matter what the background color, some words will never be visible (some things are highlighted with a dark color, others are highlighted with a light color).

I have searched all over the web but to my suprise didn't find anyone having the same problem.

Here's an example of what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: i also had this issue.. just change the color of dos prompts to all black & white and it works :)

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: with the `color` command. `color 07` is Microsoft's default (white on black background)

Answer (score 1):

Open a Command Prompt, click the icon (top-left), select *Properties*.

[image]

Choose *Colors*, and save the color

[image]

Comment: or use "Defaults" instead of "Properties" to change the default behaviour for all future cmd-boxes.

Comment: The problem is gulp overrides the presets for certain things. I can't change the colors gulp uses to highlight things through the cmd settings :/

Comment: I had same problem which got solved by changing cmd settings, did you give it a try??

Comment: I was having this same issue when running SharePoint web parts.  I ended up using the PowerShell terminal in Visual Studio Code because this showed the text correctly.  The other option would be to use ConEmu.